# Pip install py2EXE/cs_Freeze error Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, gcc, pip

I'm getting this popular error: `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

I've installed all of the python-dev packages, C/build-essential etc. ad nauseam.

<s>I (think) I know exactly what the problem is! But don't know how to fix it.</s>

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I recently did a clean install, and one of the first things that I did was update gcc/g++ to version 4.9. Now via apt-get gcc is capped out at 4.8 so I got version 4.9 from here `https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test` so now the symlinks gcc and g++ point to their 4.9 equivalents.

<s>Now, where I need the you, is how do I either: A, point pip/python to gcc 4.9; or B, have both 4.8 and 4.9 installed?</s>

<s>In fact, scratch that, I just checked the sym-link for `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` and it points to version 4.9. So is `apt-get install python-dev` etc. not making those resources available to gcc 4.9? Ugh. The gcc 4.8 binaries are still on my computer, also, but with no links pointing to them.</s>

Tried running with x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc pointing to gcc-4.8 with the exact same result. I have no clue what to try next.

Comment: I hope the excessive scratch through doesn't annoy anyone

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: I've done that, and all of its derivatives on similar questions